# Using jQuery Drill down menu, Is it possible to adjust the size?

Tags: jquery

I am using the [jQuery Drilldown Menu](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-drill-down-menu-plugin/getting-started/) and It works great. The only problem that I have run into with it is the size. I have 12 Navigation items that I need to display. By default it only supports 8.

I am looking for someone who is familiar with this product and can tell me where the height property for the menu is.

I have searched through the CSS [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6TFg7/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ndQuN/)

And the [JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/ASGen/) for the file but have not found where the default setting is for height

**UPDATE**

Html:

```
        <div class="pull-left demo-dd demo-container span3">

        <ul id="drilldown-3">
            <li><a href="#">Record Check</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reports/Statistics</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">USN</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Aclohol Incidents and Status Reports</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Alcohol Incidents(By FY)</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Fiscal Year</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Category</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Alcohol Status Reports</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Urinalysis Reports</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">DAAR Listing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Laboratory Positive Status Report</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Screening Listing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Group Profile</a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">With Details</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Without Details</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Unit Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ADMITS User and UIC Listings</a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">ADMITS User Listing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">UIC Listing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </ul></li>
                <li><a href="#">USMC</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">STAFF</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DAPA/UPC</a></li>
            </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#">DAAR Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Edit Unit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Screening</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Facility</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Treatment</a></li> //Last menu item shown
            <li><a href="#">Waiver Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">New Report - Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">UIC Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Spice</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Breathalyzer</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**Update 2**

When I inspect the ul that the other four items are in I find that they are on the page they are just not being displayed in a manner that I can see them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Drill Down Menu does not use a statically set height as there's no need, it uses an element height which is calculated depending on how many `<li>` Levels you have.

The `<li>` size is set by the default font-size of the browser used plus the padding:

```
.demo-dd .dd-menu a {padding: 8px 10px;}
```

Every time you add another link on the menu the size increases, you can over-ride this by setting a static height on the UL element of the menu, like so:

```
.drilldown-3 {height:auto!important;}
```

Or if you would like a scrollbar use

```
.drillddown-3 {overflow-y:auto;}
```

Or alternatively you can edit the max var's in the JavaScript but will take a lot of time reworking the code. Personally you should use height:auto!important

Comment: I thought that was the case as well but I have a total of 12 items and the menu is only showing 8 of them

Comment: Use height:auto!important on the drillddown3, and remove //Last menu item shown from your code as its not allowed in HTML use <!-- Last Menu -->

Comment: No problem at all, I voted for this question to be migrated on Stack Overflow as its more suitable there, but feel welcome to post again - but just note that its most likely to be moved. Glad I could help, enjoy.